# UNIX block buffer cache concept

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems

I am currently taking an operating systems course based in the UNIX environment. The following are some supplemental conceptual questions regarding the UNIX buffer cache system, and file execution.

**As you know, UNIX maintains a block buffer cache in RAM. However, writes to blocks that contain directory information are immediately written back to disks. Why is the efficiency of having a buffer cache forsaken in this instance?**

I think I have a general idea of the answer here, but would like to fill in any holes if my understanding is off. Generally, one would prefer to avoid disk access and go through buffer cache since it is much faster to do. However, since writing to a block that contains directory information is going to access the disk regardless, it is redundant to have the block cache. Secondly, if the block happens to be critical to a file-systems consistency, it should be written back to disk immediately, to avoid an entire file-system failure in the event of some huge failure or crash. My question is, is the correct idea a combination of these two ideas, or is there one that is more appropriate.

**In windows, when a user double-clicks on a file listed by Windows Explorer, a program is run and given that file as a parameter. Things are done differently in UNIX. List two different ways an operating system could know which program to run.**

Well, I do know that UNIX uses a so-called "magic number", located in the first bytes of files, indicating what type of file it is and how to handle it. Therefor, naming UNIX files with file extensions would seem to serve no purpose other than user convenience. Then, as clearly stated in the question, we have the Windows use of file extensions to make this happen. Are there any other methods I am missing, specifically in UNIX?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can not follow your first reasoning. " writing to a block that contains directory information is going to access the disk regardless" why should that be? There is nothing inherently special about directory information(it is only useful in the context of your operating system). Its crucial, yes, but the buffer cache only knows that because the OS tells it so(as far as i know). Your second point hits the mark. It is in the interest of the entire System to keep the file structure in order, so it makes sense to forego a bit of efficiency.

Comment: I don't really see how that answers the question. It's sort of vague conjecture like someone BSing their way through an exam :-). Question 1: "WHY is efficiency/cache forsaken?", Question 2: "List two ways an OS could know which program to run" - to be fair this doesn't really answer either one of those things. Therefore, if you are not providing a solid clear, conclusive answer to the question, reserve stuff like this for the comments. Take the [2-min tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get the lay of the land, get yourself some rep points, then comment away.